# Enumerate in tabularx

Tags: enumerate, tabularx

I'm trying to enumerate a (price) list, but have put it into a tabularx environment in order to align the price and description.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

\setlength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{650pt}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1.5cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{450pt}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

%\begin{enumerate}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\everypar{\hangindent1cm}}p{12cm} b{2.5cm}}
\textbf{DICOM Package Plus:} including interface and software for: Storage- (incl. Storage Comm.), Worklist- (incl. MPPS), Query- and Media-Class, Twisted Pair 100 MB & \\
&  \hfill Price:    \$ 16,225 \\
\\
 \textbf{Upgrade of monitors:} High-resolution, high-brightness 19” duel flat screen monitors (1280 x 1024 pixel) on the mobile stand & \\
& \hfill Price:     \$ 8,676 \\
\end{tabularx}

% Here I want to insert 4-8 more options

%\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I have tried the \enumerate inside and outside the \tabularx environment, but neither works.
(I've chosen tabularx, so description breaks at certain point).
Can I achieve a numbered list with specified width?

Comment: Why tabularx if you don't have any X type column?

Comment: Please clarify the desired output. Do you want to automatically number the rows of your table or do you want to have a numbered list inside of one of the table cells?

Comment: Hi Leandriis, I'm using tabularx since I then can use specified width of the column. Is that not necessary? I also want to number the rows (not within a cell), but would like price in an extra row and as such not numbered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear, what you mean with "enumerate" in table. I gueass, that you like to have automatic numbered rows with description of items, something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\mce{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}
\newcounter{RowNum}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{RowNum}\theRowNum}c
                    >{\everypar{\hangindent1cm}}p{12cm} 
                    >{\$}S[table-format=3.3,
                           %table-align-text-pre = false,
                           table-space-text-pre = {\$\,},
                           output-decimal-marker={,},    % <---
                           table-column-width=25mm]} 
    &   \textbf{DICOM Package Plus:} including interface and software for: Storage- (incl. Storage Comm.), Worklist- (incl. MPPS), Query- and Media-Class, Twisted Pair 100 MB
        &   \mce    \\
\mce    &&   16,225  \\
    &   \textbf{Upgrade of monitors:} High-resolution, high-brightness 19” duel flat screen monitors (1280 x 1024 pixel) on the mobile stand
        &   \mce    \\
\mce    &&   8,676   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** decimal marker is defined by `output-decimal-marker={,}`. Now it is added to `S` column parameters.

Comment: How can I change the numbers being displayed by commas rather than full stops. (I like that you included them being lined up by their digits)? (These don't work: `[group-separator={,}]` or `[digitsep={,}]`)

Comment: @ChrisPeh, decimal marker is defined by `output-decimal-marker={,}`. See edited answer.